# Using a callback to disable a jquery script

Tags: jquery, callback, lightbox

I'm using a script to make a user's keyboard control left/right slide navigation on a webpage. Here's the script:

```
$(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {
        // handle cursor keys
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
            // go left
            $('.leftArrow').click(); // triggers a click on the 'prev' span
        } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
            // go right
            $('.rightArrow').click(); // triggers a click on the 'next' span
        }
    });
```

However, I'm also using [FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) (a jquery lightbox plugin), which uses left/right arrows to control the images in the lightbox. The script allows callbacks (see the documentation in the link).

When the lightbox is activated, I'd like to disable the script; then when the lightbox is un-loaded, I'd like to reactivate the code above. Is this possible?

Comment: Global variable that tracks whether FancyBox is open or not. On fancybox open add callback, to switch the variable to true. In your keyboard control, execute only if variable = false. Oh, yes, set it to false on FancyBox close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.off()` to remove an event handler from an object: http://api.jquery.com/off/

However since this should be working only under certain conditions (so, turned on and off) I think you should create some check in the keyup event, like:

```
$(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {
    //check that fancybox isnt active
    //could use a custom attribute like data-active to set this as well,
    //or some other variable
    if($(myFancyBox).css("display") != "none") {
        // handle cursor keys
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
            // go left
            $('.leftArrow').click(); // triggers a click on the 'prev' span
        } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
            // go right
            $('.rightArrow').click(); // triggers a click on the 'next' span
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You both had the right idea, but you got in first. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is to check inside your handler if fancybox gallery is active:

```
$(document.documentElement).keyup(function(event) {

    if ($('#fancybox-overlay').length) {
        return false;
    }

    // handle cursor keys
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        // go left
        $('.leftArrow').click(); // triggers a click on the 'prev' span
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        // go right
        $('.rightArrow').click(); // triggers a click on the 'next' span
    }
});
```

Comment: +1, checking the overlay's existence is a neat way to go about this.